# Fetching records from one table with different conditions

Tags: mysql, postgresql-9.3

Hi  i am working with postgresql database. I need to calculate the average time between the records what i am fetching from one table.

Schema:

```
create_table "user"  do |t|
t.text     "status"
t.datetime "time"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

end

Example:

> 1. select time from users where status = 'now';
> 2. select time from users where status = 'after';

on results of above queries i need to perform average time. Probably i need to combine those two queries into one query. I tried with union operator, whether it is right way to use?. So any help is appreciated..

Comment: Please post either your schema and/or any query you have already attempted.

Comment: i have posted schema

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using SQL SELECT AVG() function, for each group.
e.g.,

```
select status, avg(time)  from users where status = 'now' or status = 'after' group by status
```

Comment: i need to calculate the average between records  based on condition status = 'now' and status = 'after'